# How to call aspx page from javascript with query string

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

Currently the functionality of a web app I am designing(I can not tell real details) is as follows :

```
alert('Hi');
var args = ShowModalDialogue(sURL,'','');
if(args[0] == 'Pass')
 alert('Bye');
```

Now I want to replace ShowModalDialogue with ModalPopupExtender. But the problem is I don't know how I can call aspx page using Javascript/Jquery and how to return values to calling javascript in the form of array?

Can anyone please help me out?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jquery to make an ajax call to your aspx.

var query = 'value1';

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "my_asp_file.aspx?q="+query,
            async: true,
            dataType: "json",
            data: data,
            success: function(response) {

var js_object = JSON.parse(response);



            },

            error: function() {



            }

        });
```

Then you can use JSON.parse() to convert the returned JSON element to a JS Object. Remember to convert the output of your query in ASPX to a JSON object (in your ASPX file).